# IntelliJ Idea React-native not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intellij-idea, react-native

I have recently installed intellij idea on my PC and started react-native application. I installed all libraries required for react native and react js. Also installed node js module and all plugins for this ide. Still i am getting error below like this in import statement.

When i move to that line that shows me error like. 
-> Install TypeScript definition for better type information.
But my typeScript definition are also as per required.

Also I have changed my JS to ReactJSX.

I have attached image over here for reference.

[image]

Comment: Which version did you install? Community or Ultimate?

Comment: IntelliJ idea 2017.3.2

Comment: Not build number. Edition. Community (free) doesn't support React. You need to have the Ultimate edition, which is essentially WebStorm baked in.

Comment: I am using ultimate addition. When i am creating app using file -> static web -> create-react-native-app.... It also shows same errors like this.

Comment: what error messages do you see? Please hover over the highlighted code and provide screenshots of the error messages

Comment: I get when i hover mouse pointer on code line. "Install typescript definition for better type information" @lena

Comment: it's not an error - just an intention action. Not the one highlighting is caused by. There must be other error messages

Answer (score -3):

You should try to create a new project using following commands

```
npm install -g create-react-app
create-react-app my-app

cd my-app
npm start
```

If you still facing error then try to use vscode editor and select react language. If you still face issue let me know

Comment: It's problem in IDE not creating in application. Also node_modules are creating.

Comment: Actually react is support in their ultimate edition as per their official site.

Comment: @JayantChauhan You can also read more information in this link. [React](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/react.html)

Comment: This answer does not help to fix the issue, specially if you already have a project well under way.. you can't just start from scratch whenever you like.